# Who sets the dot permission in ls -l output at build time in linux?

Tags: linux, systemd, ls, selinux, xattr

We have a custom build of Linux and user-land applications which contains libselinux, attr, OpenSSH, systemd, docker-ce and few more applications. We have a rpm based build system similar to fedora.
We have not enabled SElinux and still see the SElinux security context in the output of ls -l and ls -Z as listed below.

```
# getenforce
Disabled
```

Output of `ls -l /`

```
# ls -l
total 84
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Feb 12 14:45 bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 Feb 13 12:04 boot
drwxr-xr-x   20 root root  5120 Feb 13 19:45 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  63 root root  4096 Feb 13 19:45 etc
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:25 ffs
drwxr-xr-x    6 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:31 home
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root   111 Feb  7 16:11 init
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root  4096 Feb 13 11:58 lib
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 Feb 13 11:58 lib64
drwx------    3 root root 16384 Feb 13 12:05 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Feb  7 21:43 media
drwxr-xr-x.  18 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:25 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   6 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:25 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  469 root root     0 Feb 13 19:44 proc
dr-xr-x---.   7 root root  4096 Feb 16 15:58 root
drwxr-xr-x   22 root root   780 Feb 13 19:46 run
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Feb 13 12:00 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Feb  7 21:43 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   12 root root     0 Feb 13 19:44 sys
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:25 tftpboot
drwxrwxrwt   11 root root   400 Feb 18 19:24 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root  4096 Feb 13 12:02 usr
drwxr-xr-x   27 root root  4096 Feb 13 15:25 var
```

Ouput of `ls -Z /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
# ls -Z /etc/ssh/ssh_config
system_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

SElinux context attribute can be removed from a file on a running machine using the below command:

```
setfattr -h -x security.selinux /path

find /path -print0 |xargs -0 -n 1 setfattr -h -x security.selinux
```

Google search shows results to disabling the SElinux context on a running machine and not at build time.
Can anyone help in understanding from the build perspective who is setting these SElinux context and how to disable it at build time?
Please comment if any info is missing and need to be added to the question.

Build and deploy steps:

1. Build a custom linux with user-land packages.
2. Install on a x86 machine
3. capture output of `ls -l /`

Expectation:
Ouput of `ls -l /` shouldn't show the .(dot) permissions.